# Updating list view in other class from broadcast receiver in other fragment

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver in fragment which is updating the database and it is getting the data running from one of the Service.In the broadcast receiver I am updating the database first which is correctly updating even the fragment is not open and then updating  the list in other class only when that class is active,which is giving me error.Here is my broadcast receiver and when the messagestatus=='t' it will check the status of the other class and update the list in that class.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);       
        }};

        private void updateUI(Intent intent) {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) getListAdapter();
            Message message = null;
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Yea!!! Service called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String messages = intent.getStringExtra("messages"); //getting received message from server class
// String senderip = intent.getStringExtra("sender");


    String[] arr = messages.split(" ", 3);
    String threadid = arr[0];

    //Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),threadid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    char messagestatus = arr[1].charAt(0);
    String msg = arr[2];
   char ch = 0;
    if(messagestatus=='s')
    {
    ch='r';
    }
    if(messagestatus=='t')
    {

    ch='t';
    }
    int id = Integer.parseInt(threadid);

    message = datasource.createMessage(msg,ch,id);

    if(ch=='r')
    {
    adapter.add(message);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }                                                           //It is updating the respond list or sent message responses list
                                                        try {
                                                if (messagestatus == 't')
                                                {
                                                    long originalId = message.getId();
                                                    Respond res = new Respond();
                                                if (res.getActivityStatus() == true)
                                                {
                                                        if (res.getrthreadid().compareTo(threadid) == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            res.notiffy(msg,originalId);

                                                    }
                                                }

                                                    SResponses sres = new SResponses();
                                                if (sres.getActivityStatus() == true)
                                                        {
                                                if (sres.getsrthreadid().compareTo(threadid) == 0)
                                                {

                                            sres.notiffy(msg,originalId);
                                                }
                                                }
                                                }
                                                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

        }
```

My function in SResponses class that will update the list view in that class is,My SResponses class is:

```
 public class SResponses extends ListActivity{
    static boolean active = false;
    private DataSource datasource;
    long threadid;
    public static String srthreadid;

public  String  getsrthreadid()
    {
        return srthreadid;
        }
    public boolean getActivityStatus()
    {
        return active;
        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.sresponses);
         datasource = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
          datasource.open();

          Intent intent=getIntent();

          threadid=  intent.getLongExtra("threadid", 0);
          srthreadid=String.valueOf(threadid);
          char ch='e';
          List<Message> values = datasource.getAllMessages(ch);
             ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_item, values);
               setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void notiffy(String msg,long originalId)
    {
        // finish();
          // startActivity(getIntent());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) getListAdapter();
        Message messages = new Message();

        messages.setId(originalId);
        messages.setmessage(msg);
        messages.setthreadid(threadid);
        adapter.add(messages);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        datasource.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       active = true;
    } 
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       active = false;
    }
}
```

My method which is getting messages in the list :

```
public List<Message> getAllMessages(char ch) {
      Cursor cursors = null;


//String thid=res.getrthreadid();

    List<Message> message = new ArrayList<Message>();
if(ch=='r')
        {
        String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATUS + "= 'r'";
    cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
    }
    if(ch=='s')
    {
    String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATUS + "= 's'";
    cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
    }
    if(ch=='t')
    {
         Respond res=new Respond();
    String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+ "="+res.getrthreadid();
    cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
    }
    if(ch=='e')
    {
        SResponses sres=new SResponses();
    String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "," + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE+","+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID+ "="+sres.getsrthreadid();
    cursors = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
    }
    /*if(ch=='s')
        cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATUS+"="+"s", null, null, null, null);*/

       cursors.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursors.isAfterLast()) {
          Message message1 = cursorToMessage(cursors);
          message.add(message1);
          cursors.moveToNext();
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursors.close();
        return message;
      }


      private Message cursorToMessage(Cursor cursor) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
       // message.setparentid(cursor.getLong(1));
        message.setmessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("message")));
        message.setthreadid(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("threadid")));
     //  message.status(cursor.getString(4)); 
        return message;

      }
```

But I am getting this error, and I have bangged to much head with that,Please help.

```
    09-18 03:56:34.469: W/System.err(22580): java.lang.NullPointerException
            09-18 03:56:34.473: W/System.err(22580):    at soft.b.peopleassist.SResponses.notiffy(SResponses.java:56)
            09-18 03:56:34.474: W/System.err(22580):    at soft.b.peopleassist.Receive.updateUI(Receive.java:122)
            09-18 03:56:34.474: W/System.err(22580):    at soft.b.peopleassist.Receive.access$0(Receive.java:66)
            09-18 03:56:34.475: W/System.err(22580):    at soft.b.peopleassist.Receive$1.onReceive(Receive.java:63)
            09-18 03:56:34.476: W/System.err(22580):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:785)
            09-18 03:56:34.478: W/System.err(22580):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            09-18 03:56:34.479: W/System.err(22580):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            09-18 03:56:34.479: W/System.err(22580):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            09-18 03:56:34.481: W/System.err(22580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
            09-18 03:56:34.481: W/System.err(22580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            09-18 03:56:34.483: W/System.err(22580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            09-18 03:56:34.484: W/System.err(22580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            09-18 03:56:34.485: W/System.err(22580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            09-18 03:56:34.485: W/System.err(22580):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.mai

n(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is on line 56 of SResponses.java?

Comment: Well looks like getListAdapter() is returning null. Show the code for your list adapter.

Comment: @user2045570 I have added all of my SResponses class in edit question ,Please check.

Comment: What is the value of "values" at this line in SResponses.notiffy() :  List<Message> values = datasource.getAllMessages(ch);

Comment: @user2045570 I have put my get all messages method in edit question,Please check.